# Get values by using fetchone and verify when the value is null

Tags: python, postgresql, if-statement

I'm new to Python and was working on a script which executes a postgres query and pulls its result, it's just a number:

```
con = psycopg2.connect("dbname=mydb user=postgres host=192.168.0.10")
cur = con.cursor()
myvar='TEST'
cur.execute("SELECT get_id('myvar')")
    my_id = cur.fetchone()
    print(my_id)
```

The results I get are like these depending on the myvar value:

(144,)
(140,)
(141,)

Sometimes when there's no value returned by the query, I get this:
(None,)
I was expecting something like "null" (similar to what I get when I run this on the DB) but that wasn't the case.

Question number one is: why do I get the values surrounded by a parenthesis and the comma at the end?

Question two is: How "if" may work when the value is 'None'?

I've tried this:
if my_id=='None':
if my_id=='(None,)':

but didn't work..

Answer (score 1):

1. The result is a [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuples), which is an immutable sequence
2. Check if the first item of the tuple is None:

```
if my_id[0] is None:
    pass
```

Also, please be sure that you are using the proper string substitution with psycopg2.  Your code should look something like this:

```
con = psycopg2.connect("dbname=mydb user=postgres host=192.168.0.10")
cur = con.cursor()
myvar='TEST'
cur.execute("SELECT get_id(%s)", [myvar])
    my_id = cur.fetchone()[0]
    if my_id is not None:
        print(my_id)
```